# How to redirect php page through json_encode

Tags: javascript, php, json, mobile

I have two files. 1 is the controller.php and 2nd verification.js
I need to redirect once the verify function successfully executed.

**`Controller.php`**

```php
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL & ~ E_NOTICE);
require ('textlocal.class.php');

class Controller
{
    function __construct() {
        $this->processMobileVerification();
    }
    function processMobileVerification()
    {
        switch ($_POST["action"]) {
            case "send_otp":
                
                $mobile_number = $_POST['mobile_number'];
                
                $apiKey = urlencode('aphfkjshjkskshfkjshfksjhfksjdh');
                $Textlocal = new Textlocal(false, false, $apiKey);
                
                $numbers = array(
                    $mobile_number
                );
                $sender = 'TXTLCL';  //urlencode('TXTLCL')
                echo $otp = rand(100000, 999999);
                $_SESSION['session_otp'] = $otp;
                $message = "Your One Time Password is " . $otp;
                
                try{
                    $response = $Textlocal->sendSms($numbers, $message, $sender);
                    require_once ("verification-form.php");
                    exit();
                }catch(Exception $e){
                    die('Error: '.$e->getMessage());
                }
                break;
                
            case "verify_otp":
                $otp = $_POST['otp'];
                ob_start();
                if ($otp == $_SESSION['session_otp']) {
                    //unset($_SESSION['session_otp']);
                    echo json_encode(array("type"=>"success", "message"=>"Your mobile number is verified!"));
                    
                } else {
                    echo json_encode(array("type"=>"error", "message"=>"Mobile number verification failed"));
                }
                break;
        }
    }
}
$controller = new Controller();
?>
```

2nd file **`verification.js`**

```js
function sendOTP() {
    $(".error").html("").hide();
    var number = $("#mobile").val();
    if (number.length == 10 && number != null) {
        var input = {
            "mobile_number" : number,
            "action" : "send_otp"
        };
        $.ajax({
            url : 'controller.php',
            type : 'POST',
            data : input,
            success : function(response) {
                $(".container").html(response);
            }
        });
    } else {
        $(".error").html('Please enter a valid number!')
        $(".error").show();
    }
}

function verifyOTP() {
    $(".error").html("").hide();
    $(".success").html("").hide();
    var otp = $("#mobileOtp").val();
    var input = {
        "otp" : otp,
        "action" : "verify_otp"
    };
    if (otp.length == 6 && otp != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url : 'controller.php',
            type : 'POST',
            dataType : "json",
            data : input,
            success : function(response) {
                $("." + response.type).html(response.message)
                $("." + response.type).show();
                
            },
            
            error : function() {
                alert("ss");
                
            }
        });
        
    } else {
        $(".error").html('You have entered wrong OTP.')
        $(".error").show();
    }
}
```

I am not sure, where I need to put a redirection code. I want, once my mobile number is verified. This should be redirected to the **`abc.php`** page.

Thanks in advance, help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: since you're using AJAX, you'd need to do a `window.location` command in the JavaScript, in the "success" callback after the call to verify_otp

Comment: You want to redirect after verify through ajax? So then you could not need to `.show` any response.message (since you will be redirecting instead)?

Comment: P.S. I note than when you're verifying the OTP in PHP, you didn't put anything in the session to record that the OTP was valid. Therefore I'm not sure how your abc.php page is going to check that the user is ok to visit it.

Comment: kindly help me with code, window .location is not working.

Comment: I updated the code. but it is not working.

Comment: "not working" isn't a useful description of your problem. Please a) describe exactly what happens when you added that code and try to run it, including any error messages etc, and b) show us the changed version of your code.